# Lebesgue density application

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have been working on this problem but I have not been able to figure out how to solve it.

> For every $x\in (0,1)$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $0<r<\epsilon$
> such that $\int_{x-r}^{x+r}f(x)dx\geq 2r$. Show $f\geq 1$ for almost
> every $x\in [0,1]$.

This is my attempt: Assume $f<1$ for almost every x, and define $E=\{x\in [0,1]:f<1\}$. By our assumption, we must have that the measure of E is close to 1; i.e. $m(E)<1-\delta$ for some $delta>0$. Let $x_0\in E$ be a point of densitiy. Then, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\frac{m(E\cap (x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)}{2\epsilon}<2/3$ (by the Lebesgue density Thm). Then, $m(E\cap (x_0-\epsilon, x_0+\epsilon)<\frac{4}{3}\epsilon$. Also, by assumption we have that $\int_{x_0-\epsilon}^{x_0+\epsilon}f(x)dx\geq 2\epsilon$.

Here is all I have. I do not know how to use $f<1$, nor how to finish the problem. Any help will be very much appreciate it.

Comment: I think Lebesgue differentiation theorem would be good here, too

Comment: How would you use it?

Comment: The negation of $f\geq 1$ almost everywhere is not $f<1$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lebesgue's differentiation Theorem tells you that almost all points are Lebesgue points. If $x$ is  a Lebesgue point then $\frac 1 {2r} \int_r^{r} f(x) d x\to  f(x)dx$ as $r \to 0$.  Hence $f(x) \geq 1$ for every Lebesgue point $f$.  (Take $\epsilon =\frac 1n$ to get $0<r_n <\frac 1 n$ such that $\int_{x_n-r_n}^{x_n+r_n} f(x)dx \geq 2r_n$. Divide by $2r_n$ and take the limit).

Comment: Thank you, it has been very helpful.